# HSQLDB shutdown from Ant / command-line

Tags: java, ant, hsqldb

I am trying to write an Ant (1.8.2) script to shutdown HSQLDB (2.1.0) from the command line - basically I need to be able to shutdown HSQLDB from a **Windows** batch file - **after searching the web it seems like there is no built-in command line way to do it - please correct me if I am wrong.**

I've started the database up with the shipped batch file `runServer.bat`.

Here is my ant file (shutdown.xml):

```
<project>

<target name="hsqldb-stop">
  <sql
    classpath="C:\programs\hsqldb\hsqldb-2.1.0\hsqldb\lib"
    driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
    url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001"
    userid="sa" password=""
    autocommit="true">SHUTDOWN</sql>
</target>

</project>
```

`classpath` is where I have the `C:\programs\hsqldb\hsqldb-2.1.0\hsqldb\lib\hsqldb.jar` file.
All the other details are those that I use when I access the database from Java, and they do work there.

When I run it I get:

```
>ant -buildfile shutdown.xml
Buildfile: shutdown.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

**HOWEVER the database is not being shutdown.** Its shell is still open.
Can you see what is wrong here?

[Ant SQL task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `ant -verbose -buildfile shutdown.xml hsqldb-stop` to explicitly name the target and show feedback.

Comment: Thank you, this comment was helpful. I've explicitly added the target name `hsqldb-stop` to the command, as you suggested. Also, I had to explicitly state the jar file in the command path, i.e. `classpath="C:\programs\hsqldb\hsqldb-2.1.0\hsqldb\lib\hsqldb.jar"`. Now it works. Could you tell why I had to do it this way? I thought Ant scripts being run without any specific target, simply run any target they can? Also, I thought classpath only gives the directory containing the jars, not the actual jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to name the target explicitly, as you may add extra targets later on. You can show feedback with the -verbose option for debugging.

```
ant -verbose -buildfile shutdown.xml hsqldb-stop
```

As the OP found out the jar file name must be included in the command path:

```
classpath="C:\programs\hsqldb\hsqldb-2.1.0\hsqldb\lib\hsqldb.jar"
```

The classpath in a java command is a collection of directory or jar / zip names. The names of jars and zip files must be specified specifically, as these are the compressed "directories" that contain the *.class files.